# Devise routing, problems customising Devise routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

After customising Devise routes, I have some issues with the routing.

Currently setup (but failing):

- /me/account loads Devise::Registration#edit form
- /me/account/:what routes to account_controller#edit

## My routes (shortcut):

```
  devise_for :users do
   ...
  end

  devise_scope :user do
    scope "/me/account" do
      get "/" => "users/registrations#edit", :as => :my_account
      get "/:what" => "accounts#edit", :as => :my_account_edit    
    end
  end

  resources :accounts, :only => [:edit, :update]
```

## Rake routes output:

```
           activate_account GET    /reactivate(.:format)                             users#reactivate
                 my_account GET    /me/account(.:format)                             users/registrations#edit
            my_account_edit GET    /me/account/:what(.:format)                       accounts#edit
                     cancel GET    /me/account/cancel(.:format)                      users/registrations#cancel
                            DELETE /me/account(.:format)                             users/registrations#destroy
               edit_account GET    /accounts/:id/edit(.:format)                      accounts#edit
                    account PATCH  /accounts/:id(.:format)                           accounts#update
                            PUT    /accounts/:id(.:format)                           accounts#update
```

## Account

Since /me/account is actually showing registrations#edit ( Devise ) and all the /me/account/helpme are custom form fields

This has issues:

- No notices shown on /me/account on update or failure
- On failure the form is not repopulated with earlier filled in form values
- Its not updating the form
- /me/account/helpme goes , on form submit , to  /accounts/1 ( the current user id ) and throws error

  No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"accounts", :id=>"1", :what=>nil} missing required keys: [:what]

These issues are totally driving me insane. Anyone can provide me some suggestions to fix (one or more ) of these routing issues?

Comment: sorry, this is just super confusing. i have no idea where to start answering your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About form submit error.

You need to override url in your form to submit to:

```
<%= form_for @resource, url: my_account_edit(what: params[:what]) do |f| %>
```

This should be done in your views or in devise-generated views.

If you didn't generated devise views, then, just run in terminal:

```
rails g devise:views
```

**EDIT**

And you should tell us how your form in views looks like, and how controller handles updates of custom fields.